# Converting unordered list(ul tag) navigation to dropdown navigation(select tag)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, navigation

Can you help me with converting unordered list navigation to dropdown navigation?

Currently I use this script

```
  $(function() {

    if (document.getElementById("level-2")) {
        initElement("#level-2");
    }
    if (document.getElementById("level-3")) {
        initElement("#level-3");
    }
    if (document.getElementById("embedded-level-3")) {
        initElement("#embedded-level-3");
    }


    function initElement(element) {
        $("<select />").appendTo(element);

        // Create default option "Go to..."
        $("<option />", {
            "selected": "selected",
            "value"   : "",
            "text"    : "Go to..."
        }).appendTo("nav"+element+" select");

        $(element + " a").each(function() {
            var el = $(this);
            $("<option />", {
            "value" : el.attr("href"),

            "text"  : el.text()
        }).appendTo(element + " select");
    });

        $(element + " select").change(function() {
            window.location = $(this).find("option:selected").val();
        });}
});
```

This scripts converts this list of "li" tags to select>option tags dropdowns

Active page is defined by `a.active(a class="active")`.

Is it possible to change script to put link from class "active" and text from link on first position on dropdown menu select>option instead of "Go to..."?

**Update**
To be clear, what I'm searching for.

Need to find element with class 'active' from the list, put it on first position of select dropdown amd then put all other elements of list in select dropdwon

From this

```
<nav>
    <ul>
    <li><a href="link1">Link 1</a></li>
    <li class="active"><a href="link2" class="active">Link 2</a></li>
    <li><a href="link3">Link 3</a></li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

To this

```
<select>
<option class="active" value="link2>Link 2</option>
<option value="link1>Link 1</option>
<option value="link3>Link 3</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is possible, try this:

```
    $("<option />", {
        "selected": "selected",
        "value"   : "",
        "text"    : "Go to...", //Remove if you dont need it.
        "class"   : "active"
    }).appendTo("nav"+element+" select");
```

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to mention, that instead of "Go to" should be text from the link